# SAS function findc with null character argument

Tags: sas

Very incidentally, I wrote a `findc()` function and I submitted the program.

```
data test;
  x=findc(,'abcde');
run;
```

I looked at the result and nothing is unnormal. As I glanced over the code, I noticed the `findc()` function missed the first character argument. I was immediately amazed that such code would work.
I checked the help documentation:

> The FINDC function allows character arguments to be null. Null arguments are treated as character strings that have a length of zero. Numeric arguments cannot be null.

What is this feature designed for? Fault tolerance or something more? Thanks for any hint.
PS: I find `findw()` has the same behavior but `find()` not.

Comment: Assume the first argument is a variable, not a constant. If the variable has missing values, you would want the function to still work and not error out entirely. This is equivalent to the use case above except in exact syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that allowing the argument to be not present at all is just an artifact of allowing the strings passed to it to be of zero length.

Normally in SAS strings are fixed length.  So there was no such thing as an empty string, just one that was filled with spaces.  If you use the TRIM() function on a string that only has spaces the result is a string with one space.

But when they introduced the TRIMN() and other functions like FINDC() and FINDW() they started allowing arguments to functions to be empty strings (if you want to store the result into a variable it will still be fixed length).  But they did not modify the behavior of the existing functions like INDEX() or FIND().

For the FINDC() function you might want this functionality when using the TRIMN() function or the strip modifier.

Example use case might be to locate the first space in a string while ignoring the spaces used to pad the fixed length variable.

```
space = findc(trimn(string),' ');
```